# How to access java enums as URL parameters in thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, url-parameters

I would like to access Java Enums in thymeleaf.

I would imagine it would work something like this

```
<a th:href="@{/(somekey=T(com.example.Myenum.FOO.getBaz()))}">my link</a>
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't work that way. I searched a lot of examples, but can't find a solution, do you have any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<a th:href="@{'/' + ${T(com.example.Myenum).FOO.getBaz()}}">my link</a>
```

Comment: Sorry does not work like that :(
    org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "T(com.example.Myenum.FOO.getBaz())"

Comment: Yes, im sorry. I did the mistake. I've updated my answer. This one works for sure (checked on my workflow) Moreover, here some more info about that here: http://jonstefansson.blogspot.com/2011/02/references-to-static-constants-and.html and for iteration here: http://blog.florentlim.com/listing-enum-on-select-element-using-thymeleaf/